# Не обязательные группы записи RegEx

Tags: php, wordpress, регулярные-выражения

Имеется вот [такой паттерн](https://regex101.com/r/ItNqb4/2):

```
category\/(.+?)\/(:?size\/(.+?)\/)(?:page\/(.+?)\/?)?
```

В нем 3 группы записи: `category/(...)/`, `size/(...)/` и необязательный `page/(...)/`. При попытке сделать необязательной группу с `size` подставлением `?` после скобок — всё ломается. Т.е. вот [такой паттерн](https://regex101.com/r/wiIaNa/2) уже не работает:

```
category\/(.+?)\/(?:size\/(.+?)\/)?(?:page\/(.+?)\/?)?
```

В итоге хотелось бы что бы значение `category` записывалось всегда, а `size` и `page` только при их наличии. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы уверены, что значение первой группы должно быть `catalog/istochniki-pitanija`?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, да, слэш там приемлим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с жадностью. Подскажите парсеру, что нужно смотреть до конца строки и все будет работать

```
category\/(.+?)\/(?:size\/(.+?)\/)?(?:page\/(.+?)\/?)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/wiIaNa/2

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!